# How to save as GIF in Gthumb

Tags: image-processing, gif, gthumb

I edited a GIF image (no animations) with gthumb and on trying to save I encountered the error:

```
Could not save the file
Could not find a suitable module to save the image as "image/gif"
```

I jumped over to the preferences only to find save as GIF isn't there. Only JPG, PNG, TIFF, TGA, WebP.

Is there any way I can save an image as GIF from gthumb without converting it to the other formats?

Comment: All of the Gthumb docs don't list GIF in the supported formats for saving. `gimp` will do it.

Comment: @Nattgew You should add that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the [Gthumb docs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb/features) don't list GIF in the supported formats for saving. The more specialized program GIMP will do it.

Comment: Note that my version of gThumb (3.0.1) allows me to modify a GIF, then save said modified file in a supported format (e.g. JPG).